# Get preceding value in AWS CloudWatch

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch-alarms

I'm trying to calculate the week over week change of a CloudWatch metric. For this, this is my calculation,

`(Previous datapoint - latest datapoint / previous datapoint) * 100.`

**CloudWatch MathExpression:**

`(DIFF(e1)/e1)*100`
where e1 gives me the latest datapoint.

DIFF function gives me what I want in numerator. But for the denominator I can always get the latest datapoint but here I need the previous one. IS there a way to do this?

Comment: Does DIFF(e1) + e1 not give you 'previous number'?